# Not able to see Main.js when using Sencha CMD6.X

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I am using sencha cmd for the first time and i am following the sencha document to set up the application. I am able to follow the documentation and after I create the application, I can only see the "MainController.js" and "MainModel.js" under the following path app/view/main . "Main.js" is missing . Need help to solve this please

I am following the the link
http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/extjs/cmd_app.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have created is an `universal app`. This means that your `controllers` and `viewmodels` can be shared, and that the `views` for `classic` (ExtJs) and `modern` (Sencha Touch) apps are specific for that platform. `Main.js` is not missing, it is in another place.

[image]

If you want to generate apps for a specific platform (classic or modern), you can.

`sencha generate app -ext MyAppName ./MyAppPath`

This will generate an application using the newest version available for the specified framework.

For Ext JS 6, by default, this application will be a Universal Application. To override this and select a particular toolkit, you can use either of these variations

`sencha generate app -ext -classic MyAppName ./MyAppPath`
`sencha generate app -ext -modern MyAppName ./MyAppPath`

[Source](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/advanced_cmd/cmd_reference.html#sencha_generate)

Comment: I don't think that question should be answered here, because it is out of scope. this question is answered mark it as so. Please open a new question after reading some guides about mvc and mvvm (from the sencha docs) and take a look at the example apps in the extjs6 package folder from the zip you've downloaded. If